# Chat system with Video self hosted

Tags: chat, videochat

I'm looking for a Chat system with Video/Voice Chat for my Community Website.

I look in Google but all i can find is CRM and Business apps with high prices. in the past I use AVChat based on flash with a Red5 Server. but this is out of date. maybe my English is to bad to search for the right wording. but there are absolutely no app for simple community pages.

I have no problem with a payed software but I cannot pay 100USD for a limited connection service. All free solutions are not work for me.

Matrix Synapse run very well but the Clients are complex and i cannot find coders for fork brand.
Rocket.Chat very bad Video/voice (Jitsi)

any suggestions?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

RTMP only servers like Red5 are no longer suitable since Flash was discontinued.
What you need is HTML5 WebRTC live streaming solutions, that work in latest browsers including mobile.

For HTML5 video calls you could take a look at [HTML5 Video Call on GitHub](https://github.com/videowhisper/VideoCall-HTML5-Videochat-PHP) after testing the [live HTML5 video call demo](https://demo.videowhisper.com/videocall-html5-videochat-php/).